# How to trigger 'input change' function depends upon a textbox value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a range slider with text box, so whenever I slide the range, value gets updated in textbox. Also whenever I change the value in textbox, slider will move accordingly.

Using javascript, I am also changing the slider lower color to orange.This is working perfectly when I slide the range manually but facing issue while moving slider depends upon manual textbox value update. slider is moving but, lower portion color is not updating. I think its because on change function with range is not triggering.
Can you please let me know how can I trigger it with textbox update ?

My code :

```
</head>
</head>

<body>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step=".1" value="15"id="myrange" class="myrange">
<input type="text" id="priceText"></input>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
var style = $("<style>", {type:"text/css"}).appendTo("head");
$('#priceText').val($(myrange).val());

 $('input[type="range"]').on('input change', function() {

 var val = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min')) / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));
 $('<style type="text/css"></style>').text('input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track { background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop('+val+', orange), color-stop('+val+', #C5C5C5));}').appendTo('head');

$('#priceText').val($(this).val()); 



  });
});


$('#priceText').keyup(function(e){


      var val = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');   // check only for digits
      $('#myrange').val(val);

});
```

Fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/anoopcr/o07tu661/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to trigger a `change` event on the range slider on the `keyup` event

So

```
$('#myrange').val(val);
```

Would become:

```
$('#myrange').val(val).trigger("change");
```

Then it would update correctly.

Here's a working example:

```js
$(function() {
var style = $("<style>", {type:"text/css"}).appendTo("head");
$('#priceText').val($(myrange).val());
  $('input[type="range"]').on('input change', function() {

 var val = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min')) / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));
 $('<style type="text/css"></style>').text('input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track { background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop('+val+', orange), color-stop('+val+', #C5C5C5));}').appendTo('head');
 
$('#priceText').val($(this).val()); 
 
 

  });
});


$('#priceText').keyup(function(e){


      var val = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');   // check only for digits
      $('#myrange').val(val).trigger("change");
  
});
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 0; /*for firefox on android*/
    padding: 0 8px; /*for IE*/
    margin: 8px 0;
  
}

/*chrome and opera*/
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {

    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, orange),
        color-stop(0.15, #C5C5C5)
    );
}

.myrange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, orange),
        color-stop(0.15, #C5C5C5)
    );
    height: 8px; /*trackHeight*/
    border-radius: 4px; /*trackHeight*/
    transition: 0.3s;

}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: orange;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    transition: 0.3s;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step=".1" value="15"id="myrange" class="myrange">
<input type="text" id="priceText"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the `change` event after editing your textbox value :

```
 var val = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');   // check only for digits
 $('#myrange').val(val);
 $('#myrange').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event to manually trigger the change event on `#myrange`

```
$('#priceText').keyup(function(e){


      var val = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');   // check only for digits
      $('#myrange').val(val);
      $('#myrange').trigger('change');

});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/o07tu661/8/